# how to get 2 values from 1 column

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables, i want to get the values from a column in table 1 and show it in 2 different columns in result table. here are the tables.

```
table1

id name email
```

---

```
1 | James | aaaa@a.com

2 | John |   bbbb@b.com

3 | Jack |   cccc@c.com
```

---

table2:

```
id name    xID yID
```

---

```
1 | Opqr  |  1  | 2

2 | Pqrs  |  2 |  3

3 | Qrst  |  3 |  1

4 | Rstu  |  2  | 1
```

now i want to get a result like this

```
 name    xName   yName
```

---

```
Opqr  |  James  |  John    
Pqrs  |  John  |  Jack    
Qrst  |  Jack  |  James    
Rstu  |  John  |  James
```

there are 2 conditions, table1.id=table2.xID for xName and table1.id=table2.yID for yName. how do i get the result?

i tried

```
select table2.name, table1.name as xName, table1.name as yName
 from table1 inner join table2
 on table1.id=table2.xid and table1.id=table2.yid
```

but it gave 0 row. i'm still learning sql, and have trouble to understand the join chapter. i'm not sure what keyword to search, so if this kind of question already had an answer somewhere, please give the link. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

almost correct, the first name and second name is different thing so you should have 2 join that refer to table 1 separately

```
select table2.name, A1.name as xName, B1.name as yName
 from table2 
inner join table1 A1 ON A1.id=table2.xid 
inner join table1 B1 ON B1.id=table2.yid
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another answer

```
SELECT t2.name, tx.name as xname, ty.name as yname
FROM t2
JOIN t1 AS tx
ON t2.xID = tx.id
JOIN t1 AS ty
ON t2.yID = ty.id;
```

Even though the names are from the same table, if we thought about this in a object-oriented way, the names that are "interacting" in t2 would be a comparison between two objects. We would need to compare the object `id` with either `xID`, or `yID`, and then print out the name associated with the match. This is a good indication that we'll need join the objects table (`t1`) with itself, one for each thing being compared.

Now, back in SQL, there are a few ways to do this, you could of course take the cross-product of this table with itself and then filter out what you want.

This might look something like

```
SELECT *
FROM t2, t1 x, t1 x;
```

Which would give every combination (36 rows in this example)

(subset shown below)

```
| id | name | xID | yID | x.id | x.name | x.email    | y.id | y.name | y.email    |
|----+------+-----+-----+------+--------+------------+------+--------+------------|
|  1 | Opqr |   1 |   2 |    1 | James  | aaaa@a.com |    1 | James  | aaaa@a.com |
|  1 | Opqr |   1 |   2 |    1 | James  | aaaa@a.com |    2 | John   | bbbb@b.com |
|  1 | Opqr |   1 |   2 |    1 | James  | aaaa@a.com |    3 | Jack   | cccc@c.com |
|  1 | Opqr |   1 |   2 |    2 | John   | bbbb@b.com |    1 | James  | aaaa@a.com |
```

We would then filter out the combinations that match what we're looking for.

```
SELECT *
FROM t2, t1 x, t1 y
WHERE xID = x.id
AND yID = y.id;
```

Which would only give us the rows that we're looking for from the set of all possible rows.

```
| id | name | xID | yID | x.id | x.name | x.email    | y.id | y.name | y.email    |
|----+------+-----+-----+------+--------+------------+------+--------+------------|
|  1 | Opqr |   1 |   2 |    1 | James  | aaaa@a.com |    2 | John   | bbbb@b.com |
|  2 | Pqrs |   2 |   3 |    2 | John   | bbbb@b.com |    3 | Jack   | cccc@c.com |
|  3 | Qrst |   3 |   1 |    4 | Jack   | cccc@c.com |    1 | James  | aaaa@a.com |
|  4 | Rstu |   2 |   1 |    2 | John   | bbbb@b.com |    1 | James  | aaaa@a.com |
```

The are the rows we're looking for. Now just filter out the columns you want in the `SELECT`. Or we can clean things up a bit. We don't need the `WHERE` clauses. That's exactly what the `ON` is for in the joins. So we'll replace the table cross-products with two JOIN that use the `ON` clause and get the solution up at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select t2.name,t1.name as xName, t3.name as yName
from table2 t2
     left join table1 t1 on t2.xid = t1.id
     left join table1 t3 on t2.yid = t3.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T2.name, TX.name AS TX , TY.name AS TY FROM Table2 T2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS TX ON TX.id=T2.xid
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS TY ON TY.id=T2.yid
```

I have got the desired output based on the above query and below is the answer

```
Opqr    James   John 
Pqrs    John    Jack 
Qrst    Jack    James
Rstu    John    James
```